# Logging scalars from loss function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm working on a ML model implemented in Keras. For this model I wrote a custom loss function which where the loss is a sum of performances of 3 other variables `(a_cost, b_cost, c_cost)`. The loss function works but I would like to tune it a bit and for that I would like to see how these 3 other variables behave. How do I log these scalars so that they could be displayed in TensorBoard?

```
def custom_cost(y_true, y_pred):
    # compute a_cost, b_cost, c_cost

    cost = a_cost + b_cost + c_cost
    return cost

# ..build model...
model.compile(loss=custom_cost, optimizer=optimizers.Adam())
tensorboard = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="./logs", write_graph=True)
tensorboard.set_model(model)
model.fit_generator(generator=custom_generator, epochs=100, steps_per_epoch=180,     callbacks=[tensorboard], verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `a_cost`, `b_cost` and `c_cost` are computed you can define three separate functions to compute them separately. Let:

```
def a_cost(y_true, y_pred):
    # compute a_cost
    ...
    return a_cost

def b_cost(y_true, y_pred):
    # compute b_cost
    ...
    return b_cost

def c_cost(y_true, y_pred):
    # compute c_cost
    ...
    return c_cost
```

Now this as simple as adding these three functions as `metrics`:

```
model.compile(..., metrics=[a_cost, b_cost, c_cost])
```

Comment: That would mean I just have to redesign the code to return these sub-loss variables somewhere. I thought there would be other way around it

Comment: Unfortunately not - moreover - this design will show you actual values of losses - remember that loss in `keras` usually also takes regularization terms into account what biases the actual value of `loss`. Btw. if your don't mind I'd appreciate an upvote.

Comment: By redesign, I mean that I will storecustom_loss as a method of a class and store descriptors of a_cost, b_cost and c_cost as properties of this object. I saw people doing that but I didn't really appreciate why they would do it like this.